# What is the name of the react router component that, instead of opening a new link, changes the DOM and pops up onto the window?

Tags: reactjs, dom, popup, react-router

I wasn't really sure how to word this question because I didn't know what exactly to search to find the name of this component. It's a really ubiquitous component that can be seen everywhere. For instance, on Reddit, when you click on a thread, instead of redirecting the URL or opening a new tab, a container pops up on the page that displays the content of the thread. Can anyone tell me the name of this component?

EDIT: To clarify, the URL still changes in the browser, but there is no redirect action that takes place - the new URL's content is simply overlaid on the existing page.

Comment: Is the HTML5 history API the term you are looking for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method

Comment: The functionality I'm looking for actually overlays the new page onto the existing page, sort of like a popup.

Comment: After checking the Reddit example you mentioned I figured out what you are looking for. Have a look at the react-router samples, they've got you covered: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery

Comment: Yes, modal is it! Thanks a ton.